# Excel - Using a drop down to pull multiple data entries through

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm having trouble pulling data from a raw data sheet.

I have a drop down (Te Ha O Matauranga) with multiple institutions within it. Below, I am using a `VLOOKUP()` from the raw data sheet to give me info about the agreement and bond, based on the selection in the drop down.

Then, there is a table, where the driver information will update based on the institution. The issue I'm having is that there are multiple drivers for some institutions and I'm currently only able to bring through the first one it finds.

***Picture of final data sheet:***

[image]

Sometimes drivers also drive for multiple institutions, so it's important the driver is linked to the institution in the same row.

E.G

```
Swim Club - Joe Bloggs
Basketball - Joe Bloggs
```

These are my columns of raw data (15 rows long)

[image]

Can anyone help me with the formula to pull through multiple data entries for the same institution?

TIA :)

Comment: Use [FILTER()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function) function.

Comment: Kia ora, do you have Office 365? Or perpetual licenses? Office 365 has new functions, which make this easy. in other versions, this will be much harder.

Comment: Is this question better suited for superuser.com?

Comment: Kia ora, Office 365 - Thanks :)

Comment: A friend of mine has solved this for me - this has worked! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9k8CoJQ-p0